# Making scheduler application specific and not server specific

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

We have to bind the scheduler Thread to application context.

I tried using `@PostConstruct` but it starts the scheduler once application is up but it keeps running in the background even if application is down and server is up.

If application is down then the scheduler should also stop.

Comment: Why do you have a dedicated deamon scheduler thread? Spring will/should use a `TaskScheduler` which takes care of clearing threads upon shutdhown,

Comment: Have you tried stopping scheduler using @PreDestroy? Of course this will only work if application will shutdown gracefully. If you want to be completely sure even in case of application crash, you should do health checking outside of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The way I used Scheduler in Spring (i.e. Spring Boot) is by having two classes inside my project (& therefore included in my .jar after build).

**1 - SchedulerConfig** (necessary for the configuration)

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }   
}
```

**2 - ScheduledTasks** (the actual scheduled tasks with frequency defined by the cron expression)

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * ? * *")
    public void doSomething() { 
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Therefore, as everything is included in the running .jar, when the application is not deployed any more, scheduled tasks will not run as well.

**See also** https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: I am using Spring MVC with Java Version 7. So what are the possible ways to schedule a job in this case using Spring Scheduler , So that the job starts once Application starts running and Stops if Application is down. Basically  the Scheduler should be running in context of Application rather than Server context.

Comment: I get your point, however, I haven't worked with Scheduler outside Spring Boot. I need to search about it and let u know. :)

Comment: @SouravMehra The solution I posted is running in context of Application, not Server. Did you try it..? It doesn't matter I am on Spring Boot, it should normally work for you as well.